# How do I stop devices that are not on my network from appearing in the list of Airplay targets?

Tags: network, appletv, airplay

I basically have no trouble seeing my own devices but I also see devices that *aren't* on my network in the list.

**How can I get those AppleTVs that are not on my network to not show up?**

---

This image is the devices that should appear (are actually connected to my network):

[image: Expected Devices]

I'll go to click one of those two which are always in the menu immediately, but since the list is populated asynchronously (there appears to be some extra discoverability step) another one will appear and invariably cause me to click the wrong device in the menu.

[image: A foreign device appears]

...sometimes multiple times...

[image: And another]

Answer (score 1):

So I've discovered that this is a function of Bluetooth and disabling Bluetooth stops the behavior.

Unfortunately Bluetooth is kind of useful, so I'm still interested in other methods.